# Get values of multiple ngx-slider objects that are defined in ngfor

Tags: angular, slider, ngfor

I want users to rate several questions from strongly disagree to strongly agree via range slider. Since I have several questions, I used ngFor to show questions and generate corresponding sliders as following:

```
<table class="table" id="statementTable">
  <tbody *ngFor="let item of statements.slice(index, index+3);  let i = index">
    <tr> <td>{{i+1}}.</td>  <td>{{ item.text }} </td>  <td></td> <td></td> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Disagree </td>
        <td> <ngx-slider class="form-range" [(value)]="value" [options]="options"  id="slider{{i+1}}"></ngx-slider> </td>
        <td> Agree </td>  <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to show the value of each slider beside it when a user is moving the slider. However, currently if the user moves one of the sliders, the rest also move and get the same value!
How can I make them independent, so that each one changes only if the user changes it, and also each one shows its own value.

I'm using Angular10 and here is the .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from '@angular-slider/ngx-slider';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 constructor() { }
 statements = [
       { text: 'statement1' },
       { text: 'statement2' },
       { text: 'statement3' },
       { text: 'statement4' },
       { text: 'statement5' },
 ];

 value: number = 4;
 options: Options = {
   floor: 1,
   ceil: 7
 };
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason all the sliders get the same value when you move one is because they are all bound to the same global property `[(value)]="value"`.

You were very close to the solution. However, setting `id` in code the is not the Angular way.

```
<td> <ngx-slider class="form-range" [(value)]="value" [options]="options"  id="slider{{i+1}}"></ngx-slider> </td>
```

Add `value` property to your `statements` array.

```
statements = [
       { text: 'statement1', value: 4 },
       { text: 'statement2', value: 4 },
       { text: 'statement3', value: 4 },
       { text: 'statement4', value: 4 },
       { text: 'statement5', value: 4 },
 ];
```

and then change to this

```
<td> <ngx-slider class="form-range" [(value)]="item.value" [options]="options"  id="slider{{i+1}}"></ngx-slider> </td>
```

This way each `ngx-slider` is bound to individual item.

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `[(ngModel)]` in the slider, and bind the value with a key like, *rating* or something.